# Help running windows on Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

Please I need some guide? I am using Ubuntu 20, but want to run windows virtually on it so I can use some apps that runs only on Windows for now or that i am yetto fully get ysed to on linux. I have seen some names like Linux-KVM, QEMU, Virtualbox, VMWare, Play On Linux - Please do you mind to tell me a little about this? I have seen many write ups but I cant really tell what is okay.

Comment: You mention Ubuntu 20 (a *snap* only release that could mean Ubuntu Core 20?) but have tagged 20.04?  Ubuntu has both products that use *year* (*snap* only, longer supported lives) and the normal *year.month* products (use *debs* by default, can also use snaps) but they are different products. Please clarify

Comment: The easiest one is Virtualbox. You can search a guide on how to install Windows on Virtualbox and be all set. Some applications may work directly with WINE which don't require to install Windows.

Comment: Like you said, there's loads of documentation about this that already exists.  What is it exactly that you don't understand?  Please edit your question and make sure that it presents details about the specific answerable issue we can help with. If you have more than one question, you can ask them separately.

Comment: They are ALL okay. Each is different. We don't know which is best for you, since we don't know you. Try several.

Comment: A VM like virtualbox does like to use ram, the more, the merrier.  If have about 4GBs ram or less, you probably will not be happy using a VM.  Dual boot might better.  Unless you have to use Windows only apps, can see if there are Linux/Ubuntu alternatives you can use instead.

Comment: I've used VirtualBox, VMWare and settled on qemu/kvm as it seems to be more fully supported (my opinion only) although there are some performance benefits to the others.  It costs little other than time to check out the various VM environments, and you may learn much during the process.

Comment: @guiverc - Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release: 20.04
Codename: focal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need only run the windows app just use "wine" in linux, (it runs windows apps in linux).

- Linux-KVM, QEMU, Virtualbox, VMWare -these all of virtually(guest) OS runners.
- Play on linux- from wine corparation, used for run the windows's video games and offices (i.e: ms office).

Comment: Thanks you all. I have opted for VB and I have successfully installed it. as @ Charles Green said, I hope to learn as i use and try out other options.